# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance"

Tags: java, android

i got  `E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]` this error after being this the system crash.

```
  10-05 13:45:25.466 7639-7639/com.example.sanjay.samelikeviber E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
    10-05 13:45:25.466 7639-7639/com.example.sanjay.samelikeviber V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = null
    10-05 13:45:25.700 7639-7639/com.example.sanjay.samelikeviber D/ViewRootImpl@32bfe65[Viber]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
    10-05 13:45:26.341 7639-7639/com.example.sanjay.samelikeviber D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM




                                                                                                                          --------- beginning of crash
```

After being crash i got the error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.example.sanjay.samelikeviber, PID: 7639
                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:380)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:375)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:103)
```

Comment: Please share the full logs as it is hard to understand from such a short log, also maybe the actual code.

Comment: I use android Studio 2.3 and when i used viewpager and swipe the viewpager then it will crash saying E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib]] and after saying system being crash the error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference" is displayed #Adi

Comment: https://github.com/smaharjan974/contactManager check the code here #Adi